# vertx: error by using awaitResult function

Tags: vert.x

I am trying to use Vertx in a synchronous way that why I am trying to get used with vert-sync and function like awaitEvent, awatResult.
I followed this [link](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-sync/java/#_syncverticle) to do that.

Here is the lines I am trying to run:

```
long tid = awaitEvent(h -> vertx.setTimer(1000, h));
System.out.println("Timer has now fired");
```

However, I get the folloing error:

```
sept. 25, 2017 11:25:41 PM io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase
GRAVE: Unexpected exception in route
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.request(RoutingContextWrapper.java:57)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.request(RoutingContextWrapper.java:57)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.request(RoutingContextWrapper.java:57)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.request(RoutingContextWrapper.java:57)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.request(RoutingContextWrapper.java:57)
    at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextWrapper.request(RoutingContextWrapper.java:57)
```

Do you know how could I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

This simple example works:

```
import co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Suspendable;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.ext.sync.Sync;
import io.vertx.ext.sync.SyncVerticle;

public class SyncExample extends SyncVerticle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        vertx.deployVerticle(SyncExample.class.getName());
    }

    @Suspendable
    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Waiting for single event");
        long tid = Sync.awaitEvent(h -> vertx.setTimer(1000, h));
        System.out.println("Single event has fired with timerId=" + tid);
    }
}
```

The resulting console output is:

```
Waiting for single event
Waiting for single event
Single event has fired with timerId=0
```

The relevant dependencies (expressed as maven coordinates) are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-sync</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>co.paralleluniverse</groupId>
    <artifactId>quasar-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.9</version>
</dependency>
```

This example is quite self contained so you should be able to grab it 'as is'. If this does not work for you then perhaps you could update your question with additional details, ideally providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but at the very least showing us (a) the code which defines your verticle (all of it not just the few lines around the sync call) and (b) the code which deploys this verticle.

Comment: it works for me. However, I am trying to do the same thing within a route perhaps this is the reason but I still couldn't be able to solve it !

Comment: You could perhaps update your question to show us (a) the code which defines your verticle (all of it not just the few lines around the sync call) and (b) the code which deploys this verticle.